# Should I synchronize mq_timedreceive calls when performed by multiple threads?

Tags: c, linux, posix, message-queue, shared-memory

I'm using Posix Message Queues on Linux. Basically, I have multiple threads that receive messages from the same queue by calls to `mq_timedreceive`.

If more than one thread is running at the same time and the queue is not empty, am I guaranteed that a message does not get received more than once (i.e. the message does not get delivered to multiple threads)?

To be sure, I could synchronize the receive with a mutex, but I'd like to avoid this lock if possible. I read all the man pages (`man mq_overview(3)`) but without finding anything explicit.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kernel does that locking for you.

Look at the implementation in ipc/mqueue.c:

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE5(mq_timedreceive, mqd_t, mqdes, char __user *, u_msg_ptr,
                size_t, msg_len, unsigned int __user *, u_msg_prio,
                const struct timespec __user *, u_abs_timeout)
{    
    ...   
    struct mqueue_inode_info *info;
    ...
    filp = fget(mqdes);
    if (unlikely(!filp)) {
        ret = -EBADF;
        goto out;
    }

    inode = filp->f_path.dentry->d_inode;
    ...
    spin_lock(&info->lock);
    if (info->attr.mq_curmsgs == 0) {
        if (filp->f_flags & O_NONBLOCK) {
            spin_unlock(&info->lock);
...
    } else {
        msg_ptr = msg_get(info);

        inode->i_atime = inode->i_mtime = inode->i_ctime =
                            CURRENT_TIME;

        /* There is now free space in queue. */
        pipelined_receive(info);
        spin_unlock(&info->lock);
        ret = 0;
    }
```

Each mqueue has a spinlock, which is acquired before checking for new messages.

The last else (pipelined_receive) is where the message is dequeued. This is protected by the info->lock so there's no way two threads could get the same message.

Comment: I browsed the file `ipc/mqueue.c` but I'm not very sure that the lock `lock` is indeed preventing the the message to be sent to more than one receiver. Can you elaborate your answer?

Answer (score 2):

This man page describes it quite well:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/mq_receive.html

> If more than one thread is waiting to receive a message when a message arrives at an empty queue and the Priority Scheduling option is supported, then the thread of highest priority that has been waiting the longest shall be selected to receive the message. Otherwise, it is unspecified which waiting thread receives the message.

This allows you to use POSIX message queues to implement producer/consumer threads.